# Symfony 3 EasyAdminBundle Collection Type override twig

Tags: symfony

I have Entity Product with productImages. ManyToOne relationship.
I want to override product images twig. To do it, I created easy_admin folder under view and inside ProductImage folder, then edit and new twigs for test.

It is not overriding at all. Product is overridden easily is this way, but ProductImage is not.

Don't you think in theory it should work like this?
If not, please give me some clue how to override, change collection type twig.
I want to have nice bootstrap table instead current one.
Thanks

Comment: 1)You want to override the twig templates (new and edit )  only for the  with the pruduct Crud? or or every crud/table? i mean for eash interface you have?
2) what do you mean with collection type

Comment: 1) It does not matter, right now for only product, 2) 

form:
  fields:
     property: 'productImages'
     type: 'collection'
     type_options:
     entry_type: 'AdminBundle\Form\Type\ProductImageType'

Thanks

Comment: Thne what do you want exactlly plz exaplain more

Comment: Look, If you have entity Product, and then you will create edit.html.twig under views/easy_admin/Product   then product twig will be overridden. 

but same logic doesn't apply on product images, when product images is property of Product entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is curious how to override collection type:
in config.yml add:

```
easy_admin:
      design:
      form_theme: '/custom_form_layout.html.twig'
```

Then in custom_form_layout.html.twig write:

```
{% extends 'EasyAdminBundle:form:bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
```

Or extend your base form whatever it is.
after that override block

`{% block collection_row %}<div>I Love Symfony! (or just use parent())</div>{% endblock collection_row %}`